# Why does chown not work in RUN command in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

services:

  yii2-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - yii2-db
    volumes:
      - "./app:/var/www/app"
      - "./nginx:/etc/nginx/sites-available"
    ...
```

Dockerfile-app:

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

ADD app /var/www/app

RUN rm -Rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

ADD nginx/site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.conf

RUN cd /var/www/app && \
    composer install

RUN cd /var/www/app && chmod +x yii && \
    cd web && mkdir -p uploads && \
    cd /var/www && chown nginx:nginx -R app/
```

My last command RUN has no effect: chown does not set the nginx files owner. The folder "uploads" also is not created.

When I run `docker-compose build --no-cache` that step is passed:

```
Step 7/7 : RUN cd /var/www/app && chmod +x yii &&     cd web && mkdir -p uploads &&     cd /var/www && chown nginx:nginx -R app/
 ---> Running in 26a918bece47
Removing intermediate container 26a918bece47
 ---> 00db026a461c
Successfully built 00db026a461c
Successfully tagged passport-app_yii2-app:latest
```

However, when I run the workload in the "common" way using `docker-compose up -d` the change is not applied.

Why does my last RUN command not work?

Comment: I think you could try to debug those statements by executing them one by one and see if there is an issue.

Comment: @profesor79 It seems like in Docker I can not create file (folder, make chown) in /var/www/app, because it's volume.

Answer (score 6):

Your mkdir and chown commands are RUN when building the image, whereas you then mount `/var/www/app` from a VOLUME, so you are replacing the created and chowned folder with the contents of `./app` on the outside (and thus it's as if the chown didn't work).

If you want to chown the contents of the volume *after it is mounted*, you should place those instructions on a script that is called as the CMD.

Answer (score 5):

I found the reason for the problem.
In Docker

> [anything after the VOLUME instruction in a Dockerfile will not be able to make changes to that volume.](https://blog.container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker)

I define a volume with `"./app:/var/www/app"` and, after that, manipulate it, so it doesn't work.